# Android: Display a toast message after a custom time when a button is clicked

Tags: android, xml, toast

I want to add a toast say after 30 seconds when a button is clicked. Can you please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that:

```java
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Hello!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, 30000);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `Handler` with `postDelayed()`. You can find the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)

For example:

```java
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

             // Put your Toast here

        }
}, 30 * 1000);
```

You have to watch out which Thread your `Handler` is running on. If you want to make UI modifications (like the `Toast`), you have to attach the `Handler` on your UI-Thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `postDelayed()` method of `Handler`...pass a `Thread` and specific time after which time the `Thread` will be executed as below...

```
private Handler mTimerHandler = new Handler();

private Runnable mTimerExecutor = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show().
    }
};
```

Then call as below inside the `onClick()` method...

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    mTimerHandler.postDelayed(mTimerExecutor, 30000);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Toast message here
    }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can implement this on button click event.

```java
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }, 3000);

        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start a timer for 30 second after the button is clicked and then in onFinish() method you can display the toast message.

```java
public class TestActivity extends Activity{

private MyCounter mCounter;
private Button mBtn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    mBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

    mBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCounter=new MyCounter(40000, 10000);
            mCounter.start();
        }
    });
}

private class MyCounter extends CountDownTimer{

    public MyCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Display your text here",                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("on tick>>>>>>",millisUntilFinished+">>>>>");
    }
}
}
```